# Magento 2 : Equivalent block class for CatalogSearch Layer?

Tags: magento2, blocks, layered-navigation, search, catalogsearch

What is the equivalent class for Magento2x for the below:

```
core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Layer.php  (Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer)
```

Cause in Magento2, we have only `CatalogSearch/Result.php`

### Problem:

I want to convert these 2 classes in Magento 2

1.

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_CatalogSearch_Layer extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer{

    public function canShowBlock() {


      if($service) {
        return true;
      } else {
        parent::canShowBlock();
      }

    }
}
```

2.

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Catalog_Layer_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View 

    public function canShowBlock() {



      if($service) {
        return true;
      } else {
        parent::canShowBlock();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`.

To override `canShowBlock`, create an **"around"** plugin that returns your modified value.

Plugin documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html